# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl: Declared in that particular headers in class

Tags: visual-c++-2008

In my code i did unicode charecter set in visual studio 2008,When ever compiled the code link error in above mentioned.But if i have change charecter set is multibyte charecter set code is getting compiled .

Comment: I cannot compile this code.Please help to proceed further.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is, have you copied and pasted this from somewhere else? What is your code?

Comment: I have updated proper discription about the link error and let me know.